# Where I can find the current Meteor build version?

Tags: meteor

I'm saving on the local storage of the client some persistent data that supports me to have a single, non authenticated, user per browser.
I want to store also the current build version of the application, so I can check the stored values and eventually update their format.
Is there any place in Meteor to get this value? To be precise I'm referring to the build number that is appended to each css/js file url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found: you have an object called: `__meteor_runtime_config__` on your client that report the current application build version:

```
ROOT_URL: ""
ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX: ""
appId: "1wwtolm6qgnku11w1esu"
autoupdateVersion: "8215766570a26900356ccc22b4576730ed1e5f3b"
autoupdateVersionCordova: "none"
autoupdateVersionRefreshable: "c2be3e89dfb7d2b4b97edba534177bf465d7b40b"
meteorRelease: "METEOR@0.9.4"
```

Comment: Where is that object located?

Comment: is a global variable on the client, included by meteor on the build at the begin on the index.html, I've just update it's name, I've forgot to quote the variable and it was written without the __

Answer (score 0):

Simple, open Chrome console and type: Meteor.release() , you can also use it in code

Comment: This currently shows me only the release number of Meteor: METEOR@0.9.4, and it's not a function but a string